# removing subselect to optimize this query

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

I have this query that takes about 5 minutes to return a result set and I can't figure out a better way to do it. The table in question has about 15 or 20 million rows at all times and its schema can be summarized as

```
create table conversation(
  id raw, -- GUID
  vendor varchar,
  snumber number
  rcvdate date
)
```

where we store messages sent from or to a vendor, each message has a sequence number shared by all the conversation (set of related messages). The problem comes because the vendor can have a parent  and the message can have the parent's code (we can assume we know both the code of the vendor and their parent's code at the time of the query). Suppose that A and B are 2 vendors with a common parent P, the table might look like

```
Vendor  snumber    date
------------------------------
A       1          01-JAN-2012
P       1          02-JAN-2012
A       1          02-JAN-2012
A       2          03-JAN-2012
P       2          03-JAN-2012
B       3          03-JAN-2012
P       3          04-JAN-2012
A       2          04-JAN-2012
```

We need to query the last N messages from/to A and get the messages with vendor=A OR (vendor=P and another record with vendor=A and same snumber), that is:

```
Vendor  snumber    date
------------------------------
A       1          01-JAN-2012
P       1          02-JAN-2012
A       1          02-JAN-2012
A       2          03-JAN-2012
P       2          03-JAN-2012
A       2          04-JAN-2012
```

What I did was to store the conversations to/from A in a temporary table T(id, snumber) and then return

```
    select * from ( 
       select * from conversations c 
       where 
       exists (select id from T where T.id  = C.id) or 
       ( c.vendor=l_parent and exists (select snumber from T where T.snumber=c.snumber )
   ) where rownum <= l_N
```

those 2 subqueries are killing the performance. The conversations table has indexes in all the columns I included in this example.
I'm thinking the has to a be a clever way to group this information without having to use temporary tables or subqueries but I can't think of one. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to mention, T is also limited to N rows, it doesn't contain all the records for the vendor in question. Also N it usually 100-500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like you want something like this:

```
SQL> select vendor, snumber, rcvdate
  2    from (select vendor, snumber, rcvdate,
  3                 max(case when vendor = 'A' then 'Y' end) over (partition by snumber) has_vendor
  4            from conversation
  5           where vendor in ( 'A', 'P' )
  6           order by rcvdate desc)
  7   where has_vendor = 'Y'
  8     and rownum <= 100
  9   order by rcvdate;

V    SNUMBER RCVDATE
- ---------- --------------------
A          1 01-jan-2012 00:00:00
P          1 02-jan-2012 00:00:00
A          1 02-jan-2012 00:00:00
P          2 03-jan-2012 00:00:00
A          2 03-jan-2012 00:00:00
A          2 04-jan-2012 00:00:00
```

i.e.

```
max(case when vendor = 'A' then 'Y' end) over (partition by snumber) has_vendor
```

says if there's an 'A' vendor in that snumber, then you want to return that for the "P"arent vendor otherwise not.

Comment: that was concise and it improved the performance greatly, thanks, however it still takes the server 1 minute to return the result set. I think the problem with this solution is that the conversations are 4 to 6 messages long so the number of partitions is huge. Is there a way around that you can think of?

Comment: Do you have an index on (vendor, snumber, rcvdate)?

Comment: I do. I ended using partition and joining it against the temp table I described in the OP to get things moving. Thanks again.